# No renderiza react router dom y aparece error 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Buen dia, tengo una app en React con host ejemplo "app.com", y mi problema es que cuando pego la url "app.com/mensajes" aparece el error 404.

El código del router es el siguiente:

```
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Metod />} />
        <Route exact path="/mensajes" element={<Nuevos />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Además, estoy trabajando con el hosting de Firebase y tanto allí como en local tengo el mismo problema.

Comment: Ya has revisado el servidor? Me suena a que allí puede estar tu problema, asegurate de que el servidor pueda manejar esas rutas. Sin ver la configuración completa de su servidor y la estructura de archivos de su proyecto es dificil decirte que es el error, pero suena a algo de configuración

Comment: @AlfaRojo estoy trabajando con firebase, subí los archivos al host pero al cargar la página es el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Das pocos datos, pero podría ser que te falte parte de la ruta, en plan..

```
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Metod />} />
        <Route exact path="/mensajes" element={<Nuevos />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

o algo así para enlazar con otra parte

```
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="home/*" element={<Metod />} />
        <Route exact path="/mensajes" element={<Nuevos />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.